# Split video file to stream from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, video-streaming, pipe

I split a video file into two using the *[split-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-file)* module. 
There are no file part extensions. They seem like: gan-1, gan-2

I am hosting these two files on my own server.

*http://bilketay.com/download/gan-1*

*http://bilketay.com/download/gan-2*

I try to stream these two files through the browser like a single video file. Like;

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var CombinedStream = require('combined-stream2');
var request = require('request');
// Some routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Set header
  res.set({
    "Content-Type": 'video/mp4'
  });
  res.writeHead(200);

  var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
  // This function is to call gan-1 first, then gan-2
  var recursive = function(param) {
      var req = request('http://bilketay.com/download/' + param);
      // First add gan-1, then gan-2
      combinedStream.append(req);
      req.on('end', function() {
        if (param != 'gan-2') {
          recursive('gan-2')
        }
      });
    }
    // Start recursive
  recursive('gan-1');
  // Start stream browser
  // But, It does not start until it is completely loaded :(
  combinedStream.pipe(res);
});
// Listen port
app.listen(3000);
```

I created this code with restricted node.js information. No problem for me, but I think Google Chrome is different. :)

The problem is, the two parts do not stream without being loaded. The stream starts after two parts have been uploaded. What I want to do is start the stream right away. A short note; gan-1 and gan-2 files are working locally. But it does not work on the remote server. What am I doing wrong?

I used the *[combined-stream2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/combined-stream2)* module to merge the parts. 
This module simplifies streaming by adding two different files. But because I can not get the result I want, I might have used it wrong.

In short, I want to stream two different files through the browser, respectively.

I need the help of ninjas. Thank you.

Screen shot describing the problem;

[stream.gif](http://bilketay.com/download/stream.gif)

Comment: If you split the file with the split-file module, you have to combine it with the same module.

Comment: I stream as the split-file module combines. If you save to disk instead of streaming to the browser, you can play the video when you download two parts (with fs.createWriteStream). There's no problem joining the file.

Would you examine the sample gif? http://bilketay.com/download/stream.gif

Comment: You want to stream it when the first part is just received if I'm right. I don't know if it's possible to do so, it should parse the headers of the video file. Can also depend on the codec/file structure if it's possible. I can't help you for the specific media files parsing and real-time streaming while loading.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.. If there is any other idea, I am very happy.